# Swift Combine: turn error into the publisher's output

Tags: swift, combine

I am trying to refactor some code where I am currently mixing a Combine publisher with a callback closure.

The code does a login request to a REST endpoint. On failure, I want the caller of the function to receive the error payload (a challenge), on success, the caller doesn't need to do anything. So it's a bit of a weird situation where the caller is ONLY interested in the error.

Currently I am doing it like this (simplified code):

```swift
import Foundation
import Combine

struct Challenge {
  let id: Int
}

struct MyError: Error {
  let challenge: Challenge?
}

class UserManager {
  @Published var user: String?

  private func doRequest(username: String, password: String) -> AnyPublisher<String, MyError> {
    // In the real world this does a request to a REST API, returning either a User object or an error containing a Challenge.
    return Fail(outputType: String.self, failure: MyError(challenge: Challenge(id: 1)))
      .eraseToAnyPublisher()
  }

  func login(username: String, password: String, next: @escaping (Challenge) -> ()) -> AnyCancellable {
    doRequest(username: username, password: password)
      .catch { error -> AnyPublisher<String, Never> in
        if let challenge = error.challenge {
          next(challenge)
        }
        return Empty().eraseToAnyPublisher()
      }
      .sink(
        receiveValue: { [weak self] user in
          self?.user = user
        }
      )
  }
}

let userManager = UserManager()
var anyCancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

userManager.login(username: "hello", password: "world") { challenge in
  print("received challenge!")
}
.store(in: &anyCancellables)
```

As you can see, the `login` function takes a parameter called `next`, and the publisher itself handles the value inside the `sink` operator. It doesn't feel good to combine a publisher with a closure like this, ideally I'd like the `login` function to have this signature:

```swift
func login(username: String, password: String) -> AnyPublisher<Challenge, Never>
```

But when I want to write such a function I am running into the problem where I can't use a `sink` within the `login` function itself, since that transforms the return type into a `AnyCancellable`. Basically I want to turn the error into the publisher's output, and also handle the actual value inside the `login` function. How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I guess sometimes all it takes is to write down a problem to get an idea on how to solve it

```swift
func login(username: String, password: String) -> AnyPublisher<Challenge, Never> {
  doRequest(username: username, password: password)
    .compactMap {
      self.user = $0
      return nil
    }
    .catch { error -> AnyPublisher<Challenge, Never> in
      if let challenge = error.challenge {
        return Just(challenge).eraseToAnyPublisher()
      }
      return Empty().eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Not totally sure though if using a `compactMap` like this to handle side effects is really the best way, but it works.